# Sort array's rows by another array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I'm trying to sort the rows of one array by the values of another.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.random.normal(1, 1, 80)
arr2 = np.random.normal(1,1, (80,100))
```

I want to sort `arr1` in descending order, and to have the current relationship between `arr1` and `arr2` to be maintained (ie, after sorting both, the rows of `arr1[0]` and `arr2[0, :]` are the same).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Use [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) as follows:

```
arr1inds = arr1.argsort()
sorted_arr1 = arr1[arr1inds[::-1]]
sorted_arr2 = arr2[arr1inds[::-1]]
```

This example sorts in descending order.

Comment: Initially this solution was't working with my arrays, but then I realized the `len(arr1)` has to match the _rows_ of `arr2`. For example, I had a (5,) vector and a (2, 5) array, which I wanted to sort column-wise by the first vector. I did this using two transposes like `arr2.T[arr1.argsort()].T`, although there is probably a more elegant solution that doesn't require two transposes.

Comment: Are you sure it sorts in descending order? When I try it, it definitely looks like it's ascending: `arr = np.array([4, 1, 5, 3, 2]); arr[np.argsort(arr)]` gives me the output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: @hellobenallan `argsort` sorts in ascending order, but this solution accesses the indices in reverse order (with `[::-1]`) to give an answer in descending order.

Comment: @ZX9 You're quite right, and your edits make it much more clear what's going on. Thanks for following up.

Comment: Potentially useful note: to sort like this along an axis, i.e. if you're using `argsort(axis=N)`, you'll have to use numpy's [`take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis) instead of advanced slicing to sort.

Answer (score 14):

Use the zip function: `zip( *sorted( zip(arr1, arr2) ) )`  This will do what you need.

Now the explanation:
`zip(arr1, arr2)` will combine the two lists, so you've got [(0, [...list 0...]), (1, [...list 1...]), ...]
Next we run `sorted(...)`, which by default sorts based on the first field in the tuple.
Then we run `zip(...)` again, which takes the tuples from sorted, and creates two lists, from the first element in the tuple (from arr1) and the second element (from arr2).