# Sort one list from another list in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have two `tf.Tensors` A: `[x0, x1, x2, x3, x4]` and B: `[2, 2, 1, 3, 2]`. I would like to sort A using B.

Basically I would like to do the following, but using only TF operators:

```
list1, list2 = zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2)))
```

I tried `tf.sort()` with `tf.stack`, but it seem to sort each dimension independently. I think I need to use `tf.argsort` similarly to this answer [Sort array's rows by another array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007877/sort-arrays-rows-by-another-array-in-python) but the indexing fails as tensor indexing do not seems to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution:

```
list1 = [2, 2, 1, 3, 2]
list2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
ids = tf.argsort(list1)
out = tf.gather(list2, ids)  # [2, 0, 1, 4, 3]
```