# Sort one array by another with duplicate values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, unique

[You can sort two arrays using one as the leading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007877/sort-arrays-rows-by-another-array-in-python#9008390).

```
arr1inds = lead_arr1.argsort()
sorted_arr1 = lead_arr1[arr1inds]
sorted_arr2 = arr2[arr1inds]
```

The question is how would you do this if both arrays have duplicate values, and in addition you want to "collapse" the lead-array values and average the arr2 that match it..

F.e. :

```
 sorted_arr1 = [ ...5,5,5 ...]
 arr2        = [ ...4,7,8 ...]
```

becomes (4+7+8)/3. = 6.333 :

```
 sorted_arr1 = [ ...5 ...]
 arr2        = [ ...6.333 ...]
```

may be it is possible to make it using loop "**for i in arr1.unique().sort()**" ... but I was wondering if it is possible with pure numpy ?

Comment: Would you consider a pandas solution?

Comment: may be ... probably it could be translated to numpy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort one array by another using it as a lead you can always zip it and put into sorted function, using `key` parameter with lambda and tuple unpacking to pick the key.

In example

```
sorted(zip(arr1, arr2), key=lambda zipped: zipped[0])
```

In this example you'll use first value from tuple to sort the array.

You can always filter out and unpack the tuples, leaving out two sorted arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is very convenient for grouping:

```
a1 = np.array([1,1,1,5,5,5,3,3])
a2 = np.array([10,11,1,4,7,8,9,10])

s = pd.Series(a2).groupby(a1).transform('mean')

a1[np.argsort(s)]
```

Output:

```
array([5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3])
```

Or do you want:

```
s = pd.Series(a2).groupby(a1).mean()
```

gives

```
1    7.333333
3    9.500000
5    6.333333
dtype: float64
```

and `s.sort_values()` gives

```
5    6.333333
1    7.333333
3    9.500000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.unique` and `np.bincount` can be used here:

```
# set up example
a1 = np.random.randint(0,10,20)
a2 = np.random.random(20)

# solve
sa1,idx,cnt = np.unique(a1,return_counts=True,return_inverse=True)
sa2 = np.bincount(idx,a2)/cnt

# compare with brute force
np.all(sa1 == sorted(set(a1)))
# True
np.all(sa2 == [np.mean(a2[a1 == x]) for x in sa1])
# True
```