# Interpolation of points along the spline using scipy.interpolate.splrep

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm working on the task of interpolating the points along the lanes in the images. A sample image with annotated points(image not from the actual dataset and spacing between the point is also not actual) is included [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhW8m.png).

I'm trying to use [slprep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) from scipy and below are the steps I'm taking.

```
 import numpy as np
 from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev 

 #### example coordinates of annotated pts
 x = ([138.614, 161.404, 184.507, 207.297, 230.4, 407.726]) 
 y = ([231.230, 209.741, 188.058, 166.531, 144.739, 249.985])

 #### interpolation function
 interpl_fun = splrep(x, y, k=3)  ### k=4
 query_y = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 20)  #### y for which x coordinates should be interpolated
 #### obtaining interpolated x coordinates
 interpolated_x = splev(query_y, interp_fun)
```

My current observations are:

1. When I plot the pixel marking of (interpolated_x and query_y) the resulting coordinates does
   not lie in between the marking of input (x and y) coordinates.

My questions are:

1. can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
2. How to define knots argument from [splrep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) so that the
   interpolated spline passes through maximum input points??
3. Most of the related threads I see use the interpolation function to
   evaluate y = f(x) where x is known and y is to be interpolated and
   I'm using the interpolation function to evaluate x = f(y). Is this
   causing any problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your questions.
1 & 3: You are interpolating (x,y) data with (y',x') points. This will not work, as you suggested in the 3rd subquestion.
2: Please see sample code if it is what you looking for:

```
# imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev 

#### example coordinates of annotated pts
x = np.array([138.614, 161.404, 184.507, 207.297, 230.4, 407.726]) 
y = np.array([231.230, 209.741, 188.058, 166.531, 144.739, 249.985])

# we need to sort x and y together to obtain monotonically increasing y
# linked sorting
yinds = y.argsort()
y = y[yinds]
x = x[yinds]
# now we have y(x)

#### interpolation function
# note that it is (y,x), not (x,y)
interpl_fun = splrep(y, x, k=4)  ### k=4
query_y = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 20)  #### y for which x coordinates should be interpolated
#### obtaining interpolated x coordinates
# again, it is (y',x'), the same as in interpl_fun
interpolated_x = splev(query_y, interpl_fun)
# uncomment the next two lines if you want to see intermediate result
# plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
# plt.plot(y,x,'rx',query_y,interpolated_x,'b-')

# now we need to get to (x,y) back
# one can either sort again or just make a copy earlier
xinds = x.argsort()
y = y[xinds]
x = x[xinds]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(x,y,'rx',interpolated_x,query_y,'b-')
```

The last plot looks like

[image: The output]

where red crosses are obviously initial points, and blue curve is the interpolated data.

Linked sorting are taken from [Sort array's rows by another array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007877/sort-arrays-rows-by-another-array-in-python).

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answer. For the use case, I presented your answer works. But in my actual use case distance between the marked pixels along the spline is way too high. Because of this the spline interpolation suffers and then the interpolated points don't lie in between the already marked points. Any suggestion on this??

Comment: I'll try to update the question here with one sample from actual dataset with real values of points marked along the spline.

Comment: You are welcome. Please update your answer, I will take a look.

Comment: Hi, The provided answer totally works for me. Reducing the degree of the spline made all interpolated splines to lie in between the input points.

Comment: These links were helpful in knowing more about splines and interpolation. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Introduction) and  [Vadym Pasko's Blog](http://vadym-pasko.com/blog/2015/03/06/spline-approx-scipy.html)