# How to sort the rows of a numpy matrix with respect to their norm?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
array([[ 4.14022471,  3.96360618],  
       [ 0.37601032,  1.25528411],  
       [ 3.49313049,  0.94909878]])
```

Now I wish to sort this array's rows with respect to the norm of the rows, i.e

```
norm([ 4.14022471,  3.96360618]) = 5.73163455
norm([ 0.37601032,  1.25528411]) = 1.31039
norm([ 3.49313049,  0.94909878]) = 3.61977197
```

Hence the first row remains in first position, while 2nd and 3rd rows need to be swapped.

The solution will be

```
array([[ 4.14022471,  3.96360618],    
       [ 3.49313049,  0.94909878],
       [ 0.37601032,  1.25528411]])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array's rows by another array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007877/sort-arrays-rows-by-another-array-in-python) For the "another array" by which you will sort, see [How to apply numpy.linalg.norm to each row of a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7741878/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) and `numpy.take`:

```
arr = np.array([[ 4.14022471, 3.96360618], [ 0.37601032, 1.25528411], [ 3.49313049, 0.94909878]])
norms = np.linalg.norm(arr, axis=1)
arr_sorted = np.take(arr, np.argsort(norms)[::-1], axis=0)
```

---

```
[[4.14022471 3.96360618]
 [3.49313049 0.94909878]
 [0.37601032 1.25528411]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Python's built-in `sorted()` function has a `key` parameter that accepts a function, simply pass in the norm function and `reverse=True` to sort largest to smallest

```py
>>> arr = array([[ 4.14022471,3.96360618],[ 0.37601032,1.25528411],[3.49313049, 0.94909878]])
>>> array(sorted(arr, key=norm, reverse = True))
array([[4.14022471, 3.96360618],
       [3.49313049, 0.94909878],
       [0.37601032, 1.25528411]])
```

Answer (score -1):

For your task it is enough to use the only library - numpy.
**Solution**:

```
a = np.array([[ 4.14022471,  3.96360618],   [ 0.37601032,  1.25528411],   [ 3.49313049,  0.94909878]])

def get_norm(array):
    return np.linalg.norm(array)

sorted(a, reverse=True, key = get_norm)
```

It will be appropriate to use the *lambda* function. It's more concise and easier to read the code.

```
a = np.array([[ 4.14022471,  3.96360618],   [ 0.37601032,  1.25528411],   [ 3.49313049,  0.94909878]])
sorted(a, reverse=True, key = lambda x:np.linalg.norm(x))
```

In both cases the program will output:

```
[array([4.14022471, 3.96360618]),
 array([3.49313049, 0.94909878]),
 array([0.37601032, 1.25528411])]
```